# How can i limit a button 5 times per day?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im implementing admob on my app, and want to know how can i set a limit of ads to show per day. I managed to disable the button to watch ads after 5 clicks, but how can i enable it again after a daily reset?

Im sorry if there is a better way to do it, but im newbie with admob

```
ads1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        clicks ++;
            if (mRewardedAd != null) {
                mRewardedAd.show(this, rewardItem -> {
                    int rewardAmount = rewardItem.getAmount();
                    String rewardType = rewardItem.getType();

                    UsersRef.child(currentUserID).child("diamonds").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                try {
                                    int diamonds = snapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                                    diamonds = diamonds + 1;
                                    diamondcounter.setText("" + diamonds);
                                    UsersRef.child(currentUserID).child("diamonds").setValue(diamonds);
                                    contador1.setText(" " + clicks);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } else {
                                UsersRef.child(currentUserID).child("diamonds").setValue(1);
                                diamondcounter.setText("1");
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                });
                if (clicks >= 5) {
                    ads1.setEnabled(false);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "The rewarded ad wasn't ready yet.");
            }
        });

    getDiamonds();
```

Comment: Why dont you use SharedPref to store the clicks on a daily basis ?

Comment: if i store it in sharedpref, how can i do to enable the button again after daily reset?

Comment: You can have two preferences. One for date say lastClickedDate. Another for clicks say myAdBtnClicks. When user clicks on button, get   lastClickedDate and compare it with current date, if not equal set lastClickedDate as current date and myAdBtnClicks=1, if equal then get myAdBtnClicks and check <= 5

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I know, I hope it helps

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int day = new java.util.Date().getDay();
            while(true) {
                int dayNow = new java.util.Date().getDay();
                if (day != dayNow) {
                    //need proper declaration
                    ads1.setEnabled(true);
                    clicks = 0;
                    day = dayNow;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```